# full command is missing in ps aux output ubuntu 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps

Version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

When i check my process' with htop or ps aux i cant see the rest of my command after first pipe

command i run is :

```
ping -i 0.5 4.2.2.4 | while read row; do awk '{ $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",substr($0,2,10));print $0}' <<< $row;done | grep 'no answer' | tee log.txt > log_store.txt
```

and ps aux output is:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Mar20 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd
root        23     1  0 Mar20 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root        25     1  0 Mar20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root        28     1  0 Mar20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
root        31    30  0 Mar20 ?        00:00:24 ping -i 0.5 4.2.2.4  <--------------
```

As can be seen only ping portion up to first pipe is shown, is there a way to see rest somehow ?

Comment: thanks if thats the case it makes sense. but is there a way to see how a process is called at first place? I tried to look from pid/cmdline but no luck

Comment: You *are* seeing how each process was called. Seeing the shell command that constructed the pipeline is only known to that shell. It may (for example) be wildly different to the original text because it has been through multiple expansions and substitutions.

Comment: Thank you @Paul_Pedant, that explains lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've pipe `ping` to 3 subsequent process ( `awk` , `grep` and `tee` ), thoses process should appear somewhere on `ps aux` 's output.

1. note that bash syntax (in this case `while` loop ) do not appear  in `ps`'s output as it is internal to bash.
2. `ps -ef -H` (`-H` as Hierachy) might be a better choice than `ps aux`.

Comment: that's perfect thanks